# my condolences to

Tags: phrase-usage

Which of the following two utterances would a native speaker of English say to a person at a funeral?

1. My condolences to you and your family.
2. My condolences to your family and friends.

I'd appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Either one is just fine. The second is quite unusual and thoughtful.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Isn't it a bit odd that 2 does not even mention the interlocutor, i.e. "you"?

Comment: Odd, yes, but the person being addressed would, I think, assume that she is included in "family."

Comment: @P.E.Dant Is it natural to use "my condolences to you and your family" in spoken contexts? The word looks kinda formal, after all.

Comment: It is very formal but death is deserving of a degree of formality. In a spoken context, we might use it, or we might say "Our thoughts and prayers are with you" or something similar.

Comment: @P.E.Dant  How would you introduce "my condolences to you and your family" in speech? That presumably wouldn't be the first sentence, would it?

Comment: In speech, you might preface it with "let me". "Let me offer my condolences to you and your family."

Answer (score 1):

Condolences are not usually extended to *friends*

> My **sincere** condolences to you and your family.

though there is nothing stopping you from doing so

> My **sincere** condolences to you and your family and friends.

The "**to you**" assumes you are addressing the bereaved directly.

Comment: Is it natural to use "my condolences to you and your family" in spoken contexts? The word looks kinda formal, after all.

Comment: @Apollyon As P.E.Dant hints, funerals are times of formality. I would clarify, however, that they are times of *ritual*. Every culture swathes important events like births, weddings, and funerals in ritual in order to either honour them or help the bitter draught go down. "My condolences" is one of a small number of stock phrases you can use in such contexts because you need to say something of that kind.